# While pushing docker container to Heroku -> error: dial tcp 52.217.10.52:443: connect: connection refused

Tags: c#, docker, heroku

I have tried to push this container today in the morning, and everything was OK.
Now I have error: *"dial tcp 52.217.10.52:443: connect: connection refused"*

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.465MB
Step 1/10 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build-env
 ---> bc7c49365f5e
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e37155bf36e4
Step 3/10 : COPY *.csproj ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4aaa2f5498be
Step 4/10 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8b1b9aadf343
Step 5/10 : COPY . ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d5ff1e0f3e21
Step 6/10 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8a9de7e51185
Step 7/10 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
 ---> a2f206d230ae
Step 8/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fde502d1e466
Step 9/10 : COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f431a2f837cb
Step 10/10 : CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet Bot.dll
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2942c97621ff
Successfully built 2942c97621ff
Successfully tagged registry.heroku.com/cs-app/web:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
=== Pushing web (D:\Bot\Dockerfile)
The push refers to repository [registry.heroku.com/cs-app/web]
330c6215da7b: Pushing [==================================================>]  7.051MB
0e4a80eff44d: Pushing  1.536kB
de65d638030a: Pushing [==================================================>]  147.4MB
131c5f9a8492: Pushing [==================================================>]  7.171MB
ce169e1af9a7: Pushing [=====================>                             ]  18.79MB/43.75MB
cf5b3c6798f7: Waiting
dial tcp 52.217.10.52:443: connect: connection refused
 !    Error: docker push exited with Error: 1
```

Have someone see the same error today (02-09-2019)?

Comment: Im trying to push it till 2 hour, and the same get error.

Comment: I suspect you're not authenticated against Heroku('s container registry). Did you do this? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#logging-in-to-the-registry

Comment: It was bug in Heroku cloud, I think. Today in the morning everything was pushed without errors